# valgrind error in function using boost UUID

Tags: c++, valgrind, uuid

I have written following function:

```
static std::string generateUUIDLite(){
 boost::uuids::uuid _uuid = boost::uuids::random_generator()();
 std::string str_uuid = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(_uuid);
 size_t foundFirstSegment = str_uuid.find("-");
 return (foundFirstSegment!=std::string::npos)?str_uuid.substr(0, foundFirstSegment):str_uuid;
}
```

It's marked by valgrind for the error "Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation" and for the following:

```
==3203== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3203==    at 0x4D0F24: chaos::common::utility::UUIDUtil::generateUUIDLite() (mersenne_twister.hpp:177)
==3203==    by 0x52F28F7: chaos::event::AsioEventForwarder::AsioEventForwarder(boost::asio::ip::address const&, unsigned short, boost::asio::io_service&) (AsioEventForwarder.cpp:33)
==3203==    by 0x52F03E7: chaos::event::AsioImplEventClient::init(void*) (AsioImplEventClient.cpp:54)
==3203==    by 0x5365F4C: chaos::common::utility::StartableService::initImplementation(chaos::common::utility::StartableService*, void*, std::string const&, std::string const&) (StartableService.cpp:73)
==3203==    by 0x533F3D8: chaos::common::network::NetworkBroker::init(void*) (NetworkBroker.cpp:152)
==3203==    by 0x5365F4C: chaos::common::utility::StartableService::initImplementation(chaos::common::utility::StartableService*, void*, std::string const&, std::string const&) (StartableService.cpp:73)
==3203==    by 0x4B5B46: chaos::data_service::ChaosDataService::init(void*) (StartableService.h:115)
==3203==    by 0x4B7A8A: chaos::data_service::ChaosDataService::init(int, char**) (ChaosCommon.h:107)
==3203==    by 0x47D526: main (main.cpp:152)
```

Comment: minimal example? I assume the first line is producing the problem. If so, just ignore it.

Comment: i also have mena that the problem is the first line, but all seems work perfectly...